# qemu from xml to native assign PCI device

Tags: qemu, kvm, pci-e, vfio

I'm stuck between two worlds here. I have part of a VM in virsh/XML and part in qemu native commands and I'm trying to unify them so my last bit is to transform this XML part into qemu native:

```
<hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
  <source>
    <address domain='0x0000' bus='0x0d' slot='0x00' function='0x3'/>
  </source>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
</hostdev>
```

It's a USB controller/port/whatever. I found some code on the internet which suggests using `-device pci-assign,host=0d:00.3` but that doesn't work any more: `qemu-system-x86_64: -device pci-assign,host=0d:00.3: 'pci-assign' is not a valid device model name` so I'm lost here.

Comment: The script I use has “modprobe vfio-pci” and then uses vfio-pci where you have pci-assign.

Comment: usind `vfio-pci` gives me `failed to open /dev/vfio/22: No such file or directory`

Comment: Before running qemu, try doing `echo VVVV DDDD >  /sys/bus/pci/drivers/vfio-pci/new_id`, where VVVV and DDDD are the vendor ID and Device ID of the device you want to assign.